# Java 8 constructor method references

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference, constructor-reference

I am reading Java 8 book, and it comes with a sample I reproduce:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Action {
    public void perform();
}
```

An Implementor:

```
public final class ActionImpl implements Action {
    public ActionImpl() {
        System.out.println("constructor[ActionIMPL]");
    }

    @Override
    public void perform() {
        System.out.println("perform method is called..");
    }    
}
```

A caller:

```
public final class MethodReferences {

    private final Action action;

    public MethodReferences(Action action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("execute->called");
        action.perform();
        System.out.println("execute->exist");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MethodReferences clazz = new MethodReferences(new ActionImpl());
        clazz.execute();
    }
}
```

If this is called the following is print into the output:

```
constructor[ActionIMPL]
execute->called
perform method is called..
execute->exist
```

Everything is all right but if I use method references not `perform message` method is printed! Why is this, am I missing something?

If I use this code:

```
MethodReferences clazz = new MethodReferences(() -> new ActionImpl());
clazz.execute();
```

Or this code:

```
final MethodReferences clazz = new MethodReferences(ActionImpl::new);
```

This is printed:

```
execute->called
constructor[ActionIMPL]
execute->exist
```

No exception message or anything else is printed. I am using Java 8 1.8.25 64bit.

### Update

For readers that are studying like me, this is the right running code.

I have created a class the caller.

Because I need to implement a empty method "perform from the Action functional interface" which I need to pass as parameter to class constructor `MethodReference` I reference the "constructor of the MethodReferenceCall which is a empty constructor" and I can use it.

```
public class MethodReferenceCall {
    public MethodReferenceCall() {
        System.out.println("MethodReferenceCall class constructor called");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MethodReferenceCall clazz = new MethodReferenceCall();
        MethodReferences constructorCaller = new MethodReferences(MethodReferenceCall::new);
        constructorCaller.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an non-executed action inside another action. You _could_ achieve what you want with the lambda `MethodReferences clazz = new MethodReferences(() -> new ActionImpl().perform());
clazz.execute();`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This

```
MethodReferences clazz = new MethodReferences(() -> new ActionImpl());
```

does not use method reference, it uses a lambda expression. The functional interface is `Action`'s

```
public void perform();
```

So

```
() -> new ActionImpl()
```

gets translated into something similar to

```
new Action() {
    public void perform() {
        new ActionImpl();
    }
}
```

Similarly, in

```
MethodReferences clazz = new MethodReferences(ActionImpl::new);
```

the `ActionImpl::new`, which does use a constructor reference, is translated into something like

```
new Action() {
    public void perform() {
        new ActionImpl();
    }
}
```

This `ActionImpl::new` does not invoke `new ActionImpl()`. It resolves to an instance of the expected type whose functional interface method is implemented as invoking that constructor.

Comment: could you explained a little more simple.. sorry

Comment: @chiperortiz A method _reference_ is not a method _invocation_. Instead, it becomes the body of the target functional interface.

Comment: @chiperortiz Basically, your first (working) example creates a new `ActionImpl`, and when the `perform` method of that is called, it prints a message.  The second example doesn't create a new `ActionImpl`.  It creates a new object whose type is an _anonymous_ class that implements `Action`.  When the `perform` method of that anonymous-class object is called, its `perform` method creates a new `ActionImpl` (and then throws it away).

Comment: Perfect explanation! What if ActionImpl implements 2 functional interfaces, How does it gets translated?